# Como faço para que um loop só continue após um if seja realizado!

Tags: javascript, loop

Estou programando um bot para o discord que faz perguntas e confere se elas estão certas, porém a duvida que esstou tendo nn é com a lib discordjs em si mas sim com a própria linguagem!!
E o seguinte:
Ele faz a pergunta mas para fazer a proxima pergunta e preciso que esta primeira pergunta seja respondia primeiro! Para saber a resposta utilizo as reações que é uma funcionalidade do discord, e depois recebo o numero de votações na quela pergunta e liberar somente quando a variável for alterada Para monitorar essa variável eu preciso uso uma estrutura de setInterval e quando ele fica diferente de 1 ela executa o código! Porém o loop continua já que pego as perguntas de um array! Como façço para que esse loop que extrai as perguntas do array so continuar após essa variável for alterada??

aqui vai o terço crucial do código

```
 for (const i in PerguntasEmbaralhadas) {
          var pergunta = PerguntasEmbaralhadas[i]
          var exec = true
          var questao = await msg.channel.send({ embed: pergunta });

          const Alternativas = { 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '' }
          for (const a in Alternativas) {
            await questao.react(Alternativas[a])
          }
        }

        const revisor = await setInterval(async () => {
          var countAnwser = await questao.reactions.cache.map(reaction => reaction.count)
          for (const i in countAnwser) {
            if (countAnwser[i] != 1) {
              await msg.reply(`Sua resposta foi a alternativa ${i + 1}`)
              clearInterval(revisor)
              semaforo = true
            } else {
              bsemaforo = false
            }
          }
        }, 1000)
      }
```

desde já agradeço muito

Comment: coloque o pedaço de código dentro de um `while` e controle com uma variável, por exemplo`var continuar = true; while (continuar) { ...aqui vai o codigo, quando a pergunta for repondida, faça continuar = false }`

Comment: Todo o codigo do post ou subtituir o for pelo o while?

Comment: coloca no while o codigo que faz primeira pergunta, assim vai permanecer nesse while até que a pergunta seja respondida

Comment: Como você está trabalhando com reações assíncronas, isso pode ser um pouco mais complicado do que você está imaginando. Além disso, utilizar um `setInterval` está longe de ser ideal nesse caso. Talvez seja o caso de você pesquisar por _eventos_ e, talvez, sobre _programação reativa_.

Comment: Sera que exista outro método simples, onde eu consiga monitorar essas variável e executar alguma função assim que ela mudar??

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar trabalhar com yield, você executa um loop e retorna um objeto que tem o método next() que permite que o próximo item do laço seja executada, veja mais aqui

> A palavra-chave yield é usada para pausar e resumir uma generator
> function (function* or generator function legada).

Exemplo da documentação:

```
function* foo() {
  var index = 0;
  while (index <= 2)
    yield index++;
}

var iterator = foo();
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value: 0, done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value: 1, done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value: 2, done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Fonte [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).